# CocoaPods update is downgrading an installed pod

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

When I run `pod update`, `MMDrawerController` is being downgraded from the currently installed version (0.5.7) to an older one (0.4.0).

Here is the contents of my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

link_with 'OpenEye-Mobile', 'SecurityStar Tests'

platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9'
pod 'MMDrawerController'
pod 'MMDrawerController+Storyboard', '~> 0.0.1'
pod 'UIAlertView+Blocks', '~> 0.8.1'

target :"SecurityStar Tests" do
  pod 'OCMock', '~> 3.1.1'
end
```

I just updated the cocoapods gem from v. 0.34.4 to 0.35.0. The only change I have made to the Podfile is updating `AFNetworking` from 2.3.1 to 2.5.0. If I try to explicitly specify `MMDrawerController` as v. 0.5.7, I get a dependency error:

```
- `MMDrawerController (= 0.5.7)` required by `Podfile`
- `MMDrawerController (~> 0.4.0)` required by `MMDrawerController+Storyboard (0.0.1)`
```

What's going on here? Why is this a problem all of a sudden? Did something change in cocoapods 0.35? Is there a way I can force `MMDrawerController+Storyboard` to be OK with `MMDrawerController (= 0.5.7)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1** is specify same range as in MMDrawerController+Storyboard

```
pod 'MMDrawerController', '~> 0.4.0'
```

**SOLUTION 2** is to update MMDrawerController+Storyboard podspec so that it will use the latest version.

**EXPLANATION**
The problem is as it says: dependency error.

This line in a podfile means take the latest (for 04.02 is 0.5.7):

```
pod 'MMDrawerController'
```

While this one demands 'MMDrawerController+Storyboard' :

```
pod 'MMDrawerController+Storyboard', '~> 0.0.1'
```

which, in turn, specifies in it's podspec as a dependency:

```
s.dependency 'MMDrawerController', '~> 0.4.0'
```

'~> 0.4.0' means that it can use versions 0.4.0 - 0.4.9 and there is no intersection of 0.5.7 with 0.4.0 - 0.4.9.

Comment: I guess what's confusing to me is that `MMDrawerController` is ALREADY at 0.5.7, and `MMDrawerController+Storyboard` is ALREADY installed at 0.0.1. Is it possible that the podspec changed for `MMDrawerController+Storyboard`, so trying to update it now is causing the dependency error, where it wasn't before?

It sounds like my best bet here is to just go ahead an update the podspec, since I'd rather not downgrade `MMDrawerController`.